# Django include static loaded html file

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm writing a web app that requires a template to load an HTML file in a block that has been uploaded by a user and stored somewhere in the media directory, along with any images or other media referenced by the HTML file using relative paths. Is there some way to do this given the HTML file path is unknown?
I want something like....

```
    {% extends 'parent.html' %}
    {% block content %}
         {% include {{ htmlpath }} %}
    {% block content %}
```

to fill the parents content block with a loaded version of the HTML file.

Comment: No, but you can read the whole file in your views and pass it in context to the template. Then access it like any other variable, e.g. - `{{ htmlfile }}`. But Django will escape HTML special characters like, `<` or `>` will be converted to `&gt;` or `&lt;`. So, your users' images, or other media will not render. You can, however, tell django not to escape but that'd be a security risk.

Comment: I'm not concerned about security as the files will be uploaded by trusted users, the problem I find with that method is that is doesn't allow the loading of images in the same path.

Comment: Loading images using relative path in a dynamic web app will not work. E.g. if your template has an image like - `<img src="relative/path/to/image.jpg">` and you render this template on a URL like - `example.com/hello/`, your browser will fetch the image from here - `example.com/hello/relative/path/to/image.jpg`. If you render the template on another URL, the path to the image will change yet again. Relative paths  work if you have a static app. That is why in Django you load images form a separate media or static directory with an absolute path like `/media/../` etc.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing that up. I'll find a way to do something similar dynamically and post that as an answer.